# Redirection from Bootstrap modal with PHP data capture

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap modal with a form inside of it. At the moment when you click submit it just goes to a PHP script that handles the form data.

Ideally I would like to attach this modal to a URL like below:

- User clicks link
- Modal pops up with form
- If they close the modal or press I don't want to give details they progress to the URL
- If they fill in the form, once it is successfully submitted they are redirected.

I think the most user friendly way of doing this would be some sort of AJAX request.

My idea so far is this:

- User clicks link
- Link is stopped with `preventDefault()`
- Modal appears
- Form is submitted
- Link is then used as normal

My question is can I have a modal open and then when form is submitted, go to the href of a particular URL?

E.g `<a data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" class="whatever" id="whatever" href="http//:www.google.co.uk">Click here</a></li>`

But instead of going to Google to start with, they only go there after interacting with the modal.

Comment: You never asked a specific question. What do you want?

Comment: I may not be getting your question, but why don't you make the link only pop up the modal and make the submit button in the modal redirect to the link? I see no difference this would make to the user and you would not have to go through all the trouble of doing what you are asking to do.

Comment: Is there no way of having a link in the a tag, so that you could extract that? That way I could use the same modal for multiple URLs.

Comment: I guess I see what you are trying to do now. I tried posting an answer, have a look at it to see whether this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your persistence in trying to answer my question

Comment: No worries, that's what the site is here for. Did it answer your question or are you facing any problems still?

Comment: I'm having issues, but it's not you, it's me... Where I am using PHP to submit the form, it is hard to integrate the two... The easiest solution would be a php redirect on success.

Comment: You can edit your question and include the PHP code or try to look for the answer somewhere else on SO. I will check in later to see whether I can help you further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to try using the data attribute in order to pass the link for redirection into the modal.

```
<a data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" data-link="http//:www.google.co.uk" 
class="whatever" id="whatever">Click here</a>
```

Then just use it in the modal by referring to it as "link" in your jQuery.

```
$(#whatever).on("click", function () {
     var my_link = $(this).data('link');
     //...
});
```

Comment: I edited this a little bit but the jist of your answer solved my problem. I don't know if my final solution is good but if definitely works.